# Parsing IBM MQ Series Runmqsc command output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, ibm-mq

I'm using sed/awk to parse mq runmqsc output. We want to get certain fields displayed **on a single line**. This seems to be a straightforward sed/awk problem.

```
echo "display conn(*) ALL" | 
runmqsc <BrokerName> | 
awk '{ RS = "AMQ8276: Display Connection details." } ; { print $0 }' | 
sed -e 's/( )/()/g'
```

5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2009.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
Starting MQSC for queue manager .

```
 1 : display conn(*) ALL



CONN(3923A95601000020)
   EXTCONN(414D51435465737442726F6B65725553)
   TYPE(CONN)
   PID(9263)                               TID(1)
   APPLDESC(WebSphere MQ Object Authority Manager)
   APPLTAG(amqzfuma)                       APPLTYPE(SYSTEM)
   ASTATE(NONE)                            CHANNEL()
   CONNAME()                               CONNOPTS(MQCNO_FASTPATH_BINDING)
   USERID(mqm)                             UOWLOG()
   UOWSTDA()                               UOWSTTI()
   UOWLOGDA()                              UOWLOGTI()
   URTYPE(QMGR)
   EXTURID(XA_FORMATID[00000000] XA_GTRID[] XA_BQUAL[])
   QMURID(0.0)                             UOWSTATE(NONE)
```

This code:

```
echo "display conn(*) ALL" | runmqsc TestBrokerUS | awk '{ RS = "AMQ8276: Display Connection details." } ; { print $0 }' | sed -e 's/( )/()/g' | 
sed -n -e 's/^.* CHANNEL(\(.*\).*) /\1/p' -e 's/^.* USERID(\(.*\).*)/\1/p' -e 's/^.* CONNOPTS(\(.*\).*)/\1/p' -e 's/^.* CONN(\(.*\).*)/\1/p' -e 's/^.* CONNAME(\(.*\).*)/\1/p'
```

Returns this:

```
3923A95601000020)
)                              CONNOPTS(MQCNO_FASTPATH_BINDING)
```

Need to parse out these fields on 1 line. Thoughts?

Comment: can't help with the bulk of this, but read up on `awk`'s `sub()` function. You can add `sub(/[(] [)]/,"()", $0)` (or `gsub(...)` if you need global sub) instead of adding `sed` to the pipeline. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to replace the newlines from the output and then add one newline per each dis conn.

Example:

```
echo "dis conn(*) all" | runmqsc MQ8QMGR|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'|sed 's/UOWSTATE/\n/g'
```

Other option would be to store the values in variables and then print when you get the last attribute. Here is an example to parse dis qs output.

```
/QUEUE/{i1=index($1,"("); i2=index($1,")")-1; QUEUE=substr($1,i1+1,i2-i1);}
/CURDEPTH/{i1=index($1,"("); i2=index($1,")")-1; CURDEPTH=substr($1,i1+1,i2-i1);
           i3=index($2,"("); i4=index($2,")")-1; IPPROCS=substr($2,i3+1,i4-i3);
          }
/LGETDATE/{i1=index($1,"("); i2=index($1,")")-1; LGETDATE=substr($1,i1+1,i2-i1);
           i3=index($2,"("); i4=index($2,")")-1; LGETTIME=substr($2,i3+1,i4-i3);
         }
/LPUTDATE/{i1=index($1,"("); i2=index($1,")")-1; LPUTDATE=substr($1,i1+1,i2-i1);
           i3=index($2,"("); i4=index($2,")")-1; LPUTTIME=substr($2,i3+1,i4-i3)
          }
/MSGAGE/{i3=index($2,"("); i4=index($2,")")-1; MSGAGE=substr($2,i3+1,i4-i3);}
/OPPROCS/{i1=index($1,"("); i2=index($1,")")-1; OPPROCS=substr($1,i1+1,i2-i1);
          i3=index($2,"("); i4=index($2,",")-1; QTIME=substr($2,i3+1,i4-i3);
          i5=1; i6=index($3,")")-1; QTIME2=substr($3,i5,i6-i5+1);
         }
/UNCOM/{
          i1=index($1,"("); i2=index($1,")")-1; UNCOM=substr($1,i1+1,i2-i1);

           if( QUEUE == "SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE" )
           {
               print date "|" QUEUE  "|" CURDEPTH "|" LGETDATE "|" LGETTIME "|" LPUTDATE  "|" LPUTTIME "|" MSGAGE "|" QTIME "," QTIME2 "|" UNCOM;
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env gawk -f
#
# Parses output of 'runmqsc' command and prints a comma separated list of the
# attributes on one line per object.
#
# CAVEAT: Fails if '(' or ')' characters are in attribute values (e.g.  DESC)
#
# Daniel Steinmann, Mai 2015

function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
function trim(s)  { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }

BEGIN {
    RS = "AMQ[0-9]+: [^.]*."
    FS = "[()]"
}
{
    # Filter out header
    if (NR == 1) next
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i = i+2) {
        key = trim($i)
        value = trim($(i+1))
        # Filter out empty lines and trailer
        if (key ~ /[ ]/ || key == "") continue
        if (i > 1) printf(", ")
        printf("%s(%s)", key, value)
    }
    printf("\n")
}
```

It produces output like this:

```
$ echo "display conn(*) all | runmqsc MYQMGR | ./parse_runmqsc_output.gawk
CONN(F290EE5720001801), EXTCONN(414D51435858582E534232492E4D4149), ...
CONN(F290EE572009F312), EXTCONN(414D51435858582E534232492E4D4149), ...
```

You can easily adapt the `gawk` script to produce output the way you want.